# Updating multiple UI Elements inside Timer.scheduledTimer doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I am trying to make an image "move down" every second while also showing a time counter. I have a scheduledTimer where I change the image's Y center and update the timer. The timer label updates but the image does not move. Strangely I can get the image to move down if I comment the line where I update the timer's UILabel. So apparently I can't update both.

I have tried adding the Timer to RunLoop, using a DispatchQueue and creating a Timer that takes a selector but nothing works.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let starImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"))
    let timerLabel = UILabel()
    var counter = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        
        setupViews()
        gameEngine()
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(starImage)
        starImage.tintColor = .systemYellow
        starImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(timerLabel)
        timerLabel.tintColor = .white
        timerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ 
            starImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            starImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            starImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            starImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        
            timerLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
            timerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        ])
    }

    // PROBLEM HERE
    private func gameEngine() {
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {
            [weak self] _ in
            self?.counter += 1
            self?.timerLabel.text = "Timer: \(self!.counter)"
            self?.starImage.center.y += 10
        }
    }
  
}
```

I got it to work by using UIView.animate as Rob suggested it in the comments.
I replaced the line where I updated the Y value with this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    [weak self] in
    self?.starImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: CGFloat(self!.counter*100))
})
```

Comment: Have you tried using `UIView.animate` with `starImage.transform` instead of `center.y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1. Instead
   *timerLabel.tintColor = .white* you need to use *timerLabel.textColor = .white*

2.To move starImage you need update constraint:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let starImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"))
    let timerLabel = UILabel()
    var counter = 0
    var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        
        setupViews()
        gameEngine()
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(starImage)
        starImage.tintColor = .systemYellow
        starImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(timerLabel)
        timerLabel.tintColor = .white
        timerLabel.textColor = .white
        timerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            topConstraint =             starImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            starImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            starImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            topConstraint!,
            starImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        
            timerLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
            timerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        ])
    }

    // PROBLEM HERE
    private func gameEngine() {
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {
            [weak self] _ in
            self?.counter += 1
            self?.timerLabel.text = "Timer: \(self!.counter)"
            self!.topConstraint?.constant += 10
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I also thought about it being a matter of constraint, but if it were then it should not work in any case. The image does move down if I don't update the timerLabel's text.

Comment: It works for me. Anyway if you use constraints you need to change constraints.

Comment: The line you added does not compile. I have added a constraint to the topAnchor of the imageView and it did not make any difference.

Comment: I added more than 1 line. Try to create a new project and put this code instead of the default ViewController

Comment: You are right, my bad. I did not see the other lines, I apologise. It works perfectly.